# How to get Application id(package + modulename) delphi XE5/XE6/XE7

Tags: android, ios, delphi

Is there a way to get the application id in runtime for Android and iOS in delphi XE7?

For android you can see the application id at:
project options -> version info(Target Android) -> package 
and for iOS:
project options -> version info(Target iOS) -> CFBundleName

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading Android package name:

```
uses
  Androidapi.Helpers;

function PackageName: string;
begin
  Result := JStringToString(SharedActivityContext.getPackageName);
end;
```

Reading iOS bundle name:

```
uses
  Macapi.CoreFoundation, iOSApi.Foundation;

function PackageName: string;
begin
  Result := TNSString.Wrap(CFBundleGetValueForInfoDictionaryKey(CFBundleGetMainBundle, kCFBundleIdentifierKey)).UTF8String;
end;
```